# Can Mass Effect 2 Saves and DLC be used on multiple Xboxes with the same Live Profile?

Tags: xbox-network, mass-effect-2

I have one XBox 360 in my house, and plan to buy a second console for my office (across the country).  I'm playing Mass Effect 2 (using Cloud Storage for Saves).  I've bought all of the DLC and thus far have done all of my playing on my primary console.

I'm trying to determine if I will be able to download all of the DLC to the second XBox and continue to play no matter which location I'm in. Basically I want to be able to continue playing/progressing even as I travel from location to location.

I'm fairly confident that my Cloud based saves will work just fine, but it's very hard to pin down the policy on DLC and multiple XBoxes.  Obviously I'll be using the same Xbox Live Profile in both locations.

Will I have to buy the Cerberus Network for the second Xbox?  Will I have to re-buy all of the DLC?

Comment: Just confirming that the accepted answer ended up being 100% correct. I've been able to use my cloud save and all of my DLC, including the cerberus network from a second xbox 360.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine in re-downloading the DLC to the second console assuming you can sign into Xbox Live with the same profile it's licensed to. The content is licensed to your profile as well as to the original console it was purchased/downloaded on, so if you can sign in on another console, then it will let you use it on that console while signed in.

Also, I confirmed that the Cerberus Network appears to load fine on a second console without having to download anything. I'm assuming it must be tied to the EA Profile which is linked to your Xbox Live profile, and doesn't require any sort of download.

Comment: Is this true for the Cerberus Network as well?  This one might be tricky since it's a code that comes with the game and entered directly into the game, not into the Xbox Marketplace.

Comment: I'll have to see if I can fire up my 2nd console to check this. Forgot the Cerberus is an in-game thing. I wonder if it's tied to the EA account you sign in with.

Comment: I'm guessing it probably is tied to the EA account. But I dont' even remember creating or signing in with an EA account.  If Cerberus Network is the only thing I have to re-buy, I'm ok with that.  I just don't want to re-buy the 60+ dollars worth of DLC.

Comment: @bconneen just fired up my 2nd console (been sitting in it's new box for awhile), downloaded my profile, fired up Mass Effect 2 for the first time, and Cerberus Network loaded automatically. I'm assuming it's tied to the EA Profile that is tied to my Live profile. I've never signed in to this console before with this profile and didn't sign in to the EA Profile on this console either. It just knew. Somehow.

Comment: I appreciate you going the extra mile to answer my question.